# Can't get JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to get a JSON array that I return in a php page.
I have a script that is called onload of a document and the script has the following code:

```
function parses() {
  alert("sdas");
  $.ajax({ 
    url: myURL,
    type: "GET", 
    data: query, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (data){ 
      alert(data); 
    } 
  });
}
```

It doesn't alert the data, I'm guessing it isn't receiving the JSON array.

Comment: What do the requests from the page look like? What response does it get?

Comment: If you're using Firefox or Chrome, what requests (if any) do you see being made in the Network tab of the web inspector?

Comment: If it doesn't alert the data it means that your callback function is not executing at all. My guess would be that you're having a json parse error. Use the `error` property to debug your error message.

Comment: only the html file including the css file and the script, .js file

Comment: success: function (data){ 
          alert(data); 
        } ,
        error: function(e, xhr){
          alert(xhr);
        }
added this but it doesn't alert anything

Comment: Type your url and query string into a browser and see what response it displays.

Comment: It gives an error. It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined " when I inspect the element

Comment: Well you know you should first include the jquery lib and only then use it's goodies, right?

Comment: How do I include the library in the script?

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` But please Google, before asking something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check this on Chrome, so don't just guess. 
Open a tab in chrome and then open "Developer tools", then go to network tab there. 
So you will see if the AJAX request being sent or not, if there is any js error which is 
holding AJAX request, you will see that in "Console" tab of developer tools.

My guess is you may be trying to do this even before loading and initializing jQuery.